# Is there an app that runs Java (.jar) files on Android?

Tags: android, java, emulator

I would like to run a .jar file on my Samsung Galaxy S5 Android phone.

I expect that it requires an app, but I can't find such app anywhere.

What app would be great to emulate .jar files, preferably without a .jar size limit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even though Android uses Java, it does not support executing JAR files on Android devices. However, you can use emulators to do this which are not available on Google Play Store but are available from the developers' website. I have provided the source link and download instructions are available there.

1. phoneME
2. JBlend
3. Netmite
4. JBED

Features of **phoneME**:

- phoneME for Windows CE/Mobile and Android is an implementation of the
  phoneME open source J2ME application platform for your Windows Mobile
  phone or Android handheld device.
- Each build includes the phoneME VM and an Android frontend wrapper
  with JNI bindings to the VM.
- Most powerful, smooth user experience, less crashes.
- JAD files are also associated with the Foundation Profile-MIDP
  Android application. Therefore, you can also use your browser to
  select an online JAD file to download and run the midlet. If you
  click on a JAD download link, a popup menu will appear and you need
  to choose the Foundation Profile-MIDP Android application
- No root access required.

---

Features of **Netmite App Runner**:

- This is the most popular application to run Java apps and games
  (J2ME/MIDP – jar/jad) app on Android OS.
- This application has App Explorer, which helps to find existing Java
  apps and games on your phone/tablet device.
- It is integrated with Browser-Browse any j2me site, click to run any
  jad/jar file.
- It can auto-convert J2ME into Android package (apk) on the fly.
- You can immediately port your existing Java apps (jar/jad) to Android
  WITHOUT source code.

---

Features **JBED**:

- JBED is also a very good Java/J2ME Emulator for Android.
- It is fast but has some issue like – screen got hazy on landscape
  mode, unexpected force close.
- It has built in app explorer.

---

Features **JBlend**:

- JBlend is very Similar to JBED and much better.
- It’s smooth and never crashes.
- Support most Java apps / games

---

***Important! It's possible that not all emulators will work for your devices.
Each emulator has different features. You have the option to try different emulators, and decide which one you want to use.***

[Sources](http://w3epic.com/run-java-apps-j2me-on-android-devices-guide/)

Comment: Usually we frown on 1:1 copies – but I had to +1 as "thanks for the hint" ;) And after all, you made clear it is one and named the source... Good find!

Comment: Linked and credited from my [list of emulators](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/emulators) (see the end of that page) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just create a Android project in IntellJ, NetBeans or Eclipse,
add your jar to the libs directory and write your little Android
GUI for it.

Answer (score 1):

So, just to keep this updated with something that wasn't supposed to run on 2.2.. 
And just because I think it's a shame that tons of project went wasted because they weren't open source

This is what I would recommend to try in 2019 (in no special order)

- [phoneME](http://davy.preuveneers.be/phoneme/?q=node/28) (again, but it was tentatively fixed for newer OS versions)
- [J2ME Loader](https://github.com/nikita36078/J2ME-Loader/) (it seems the most actively supported and promising)
- [MicroEmu](https://github.com/artem-frolov/microemu) (this should be more about converting applets into apks technically)
- [SquirrelJME](https://github.com/XerTheSquirrel/SquirrelJME) (AFAIK the dev should be in the process of wiring Android support)

Of course all of these are targeting the limited mobile J2ME, rather than the desktop J2SE (I wonder why nobody still thought to that)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this app called java runtime environment:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.coobbi.jre

Answer (score 0):

pojav launcher works i know its crazy but it does

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.kdt.pojavlaunch&hl=en&gl=US

https://github.com/PojavLauncherTeam/PojavLauncher

Comment: oh its 8 years old? LOL

Comment: Despite the age, the answer needs a review

Comment: helper: To make a quality answer, please add a screenshot (or explanation) showing how to run an arbitrary jar. Thanks!